# Does Tomcat make use of webdefault.xml?

Tags: tomcat, jetty

I'm working on a project that originally used Jetty for its webapps. As the project progressed, it eventually switched to Tomcat. These webapps all contain `webdefault.xml` files, which based on googling appear to be heavily associated with Jetty and rarely talked about in Tomcat contexts, suggesting that the files are just a remnant that someone forgot to delete.

Is `webdefault.xml` exclusively used by Jetty (and thus safely removable) or does Tomcat (and/or other servers) still make use of it?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently moved from Jetty to tomcat.I believe Tomcat uses ../conf/web.xml instead of webdefault.xml.So,try removing the webdefault.xml 's and see, it should work.

Comment: Indeed. Since this question was originally asked, the `webdefault.xml` files have been deleted with no apparent effect whatsoever.